# Why is my Honeywell alarm system not powering down?

Tags: transformer, alarm

I have a circa 2005 Honeywell Vista alarm system that I would like to power down so that the battery alert never goes off.

Following the advice on various YouTube videos and this community, I first found the alarm system box and disconnected the two batteries that were there. Then I found the transformer and removed it from the outlet, but there are still wires coming out of the outlet (see picture), and the alarm display itself
continues to function.

That confuses me because it shouldn’t have any power source! I even turned off the circuit breaker for the outlet that the transformer was plugged in to. So what am I missing? How do I successfully power down the system?

Separately, are the wires coming out of the outlet a safety hazard? If so, how do I fix this?

Update: I managed to open the console, but there’s no console battery to be found. See the last image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: That small wire coming out of the outlet is a big no-no.  The black stains might be a concern or a sign you don't clean well.  Black stains on electrical devices could be a sign of smoke/fire, or a slob, only you will know.  The indicator might have a small battery to let you know the main battery is down.

Comment: What do you recommend I do with the small wire coming out of the outlet? It seems to be wired directly into the back of the outlet. The transformer is near the hot water heater but I can’t think of anything “external” that would stain it. Finally, are you suggesting I should remove a battery in the alarm console itself?

Comment: Turn off the breaker and remove the small wire.  Alarm systems probably quite picky if start to remove too much.  Removing the big batteries and the transformer the alarm system basically dead, with only a watch or nine volt battery supplying power.

Comment: What does it mean to “remove the wire”? Snip it? Or take out outlet and see if I can unwire it from outlet? Separately, I opened console, and there didn’t appear to be any built in power source, so now I’m really confused where the power is coming from if not the battery or transformer.

Comment: Remove is to remove completely/unwire/disconnect.  No reason a small wire like that should be on a 120 volt circuit.  If those wires are connected, then touching them would give at minimum a very painful shock.

Comment: I begin to wonder if you have two alarm systems, and the one you disconnected (or the power supply you disconnected) is not the one the panel is connected to. If you have a voltmeter, start checking the alarm panel for voltage

Comment: I actually pulled apart the console in my last picture in the main post and still saw the green LEDs lit up. So I tu I you’re right that power is clearly still flowing to the alarm console.

Comment: Remove wires = use voltmeter, check carefully for voltage on wires, plug something into the outlet, make sure that whatever you plug in shuts off when you shut off the breaker you think goes to the outlet, remove the outlet with the breaker shut off, see what's actually connected to what back there, and get those small code-violating wires out of the outlet box.

Comment: One more thing to try. On the main board, in the upper left corner is a fuse (glass tube with metal ends) in a holder. Try pulling out the fuse to see if that will kill it. Careful, there may be mains voltage there. Wear rubber gloves when removing the fuse.

Comment: You might try disconnecting the two wires from the first two screw terminals on the left side of the circuit board.  The wiring digram shows these as a 16.5 volt supply so if you haven't found the transformer it may still be connected at the other end of those two wires.

Comment: @DoxyLover there is no mains voltage here. 16.5VAC and 12VDC only. And the fuse is for the battery, as labeled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FC indicates communications failure (telephone)

AC means **it's getting AC power (from a transformer, obviously not that one.)** Follow the green and yellow wires on terminals 1&2 that seem to go out the left side of the box. Alternatively, turn off breakers until you find one that turns it off, and then you'll perhaps have a better idea where to search for the transformer. One possibility is that it's hidden behind the alarm system box.

Bat means the battery is low (no duh, it's disconnected - or we think it is, or at least the one on the decoy alarm system is...)

Not ready means it's not ready for arming (open zones.)

Manual link [here](https://zionssecurity.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/V15_20P-User-Guide.pdf) (if it works.)

Comment: Interesting! I am still seeing AC on the console, so I guess there is another transformer somewhere. So what could that other transformer be for? Hot water heater manual did not require a transformer.

Comment: Almost anything. If nothing stops working, some other obsolete thing. hard to know unless you follow the wires to where they go. Do you have doorbell (not that that is a usual format for a doorbell transformer?)

Comment: The wire looks like thermostat wire, (red/white in a brown jacket)  but that really does not narrow it down any, and the voltage is more typical of alarm supplies than thermostat supplies.

Comment: It’s definitely not the thermostat since I removed the transformer and the thermostat still works great.

Comment: @Ecernewal your doorbell guess was correct!

Comment: @Ecnerwal if your answer gets accepted, OP also deserves vote up for assking clear question.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, folks it turns out that transformer I unplugged was for the doorbell.

I’ve looked all over the house and can’t find a second transformer, but for now I believe that merely holding the “off” button on the alarm is sufficient to keep it from beeping in the middle of the night.

Comment: Try taking the disconnected-but-heavy batteries out, loosening the mounting screws, lifting the alarm panel mounting screws and lifting the box up and away from the wall to peek behind it. Or, simply disconnect and tape up the two wires on terminals 1&2 - it's 16.5 VAC so should not be dangerous, and would be preferable to find and disconnect the transformer, but if you want the alarm dead, that will do that. You still need to correct the way your doorbell was wired, too.